# How do I avoid a slow loop with large data set?

Tags: r, dataframe, large-data

Consider this data set:

```
> DATA <- data.frame(Agreement_number = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
+                    country = c("Canada","Canada", "USA", "USA", "Canada","Canada", "USA", "USA"), 
+                    action = c("signature", "ratification","signature", "ratification", "signature", "ratification","signature", "ratification"), 
+                    signature_date = c(2000,NA,2000,NA, 2001, NA, 2002, NA),
+                    ratification_date = c(NA, 2001, NA, 2002, NA, 2001, NA, 2002))
> DATA
Agreement_number country       action signature_date ratification_date
              1  Canada    signature           2000                NA
             1  Canada ratification             NA              2001
             1     USA    signature           2000                NA
             1     USA ratification             NA              2002
             2  Canada    signature           2001                NA
             2  Canada ratification             NA              2001
             2     USA    signature           2002                NA
             2     USA ratification             NA              2002
```

As you can see, half of the rows have duplicate information. For a small data set like this it is really easy to remove duplicates. I could use the `coalesce` function ([dplyr package](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr)), get rid of the "action" column and then erase all the irrelevant rows. Though, there many other ways. The final result should look like this:

```
> DATA <- data.frame( Agreement_number = c(1,1,2,2),
+                     country = c("Canada", "USA", "Canada","USA"), 
+                     signature_date = c(2000,2000,2001,2002),
+                     ratification_date = c(2001, 2002, 2001, 2002))
> DATA
Agreement_number country signature_date ratification_date
             1  Canada           2000              2001
             1     USA           2000              2002
             2  Canada           2001              2001
             2     USA           2002              2002
```

The problem, is that my real data set is MUCH bigger (102000 x 270) and there are many more variables. The real data is also more irregular and there are more absent values. The `coalesce` function seems very slow. The best loop I could make so far still takes up to 5-10 minutes to run.

Is there a simple way of doing this which would be faster? I have the feeling that there must be some function in R for that kind of operation, but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've made some edits to your question to improve clarity to help you get an answer. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567075/combining-pivoted-rows-in-r-by-common-value/42567254

Comment: thanks for your answers to everybody! I actually solved the problem earlier in my code, but I was inspired by your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP has told that his production data has 100 k rows x 270 columns, and speed is a concern for him. Therefore, I suggest to use `data.table`.

I'm aware that [Harland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427418/3817004) also has proposed to use `data.table` and `dcast()` but the solution below is a different approach. It brings the rows in the correct order and copies the `ratification_date` to the signature row. After some clean-up we get the desired result.

```
library(data.table)

# coerce to data.table,
# make sure that the actions are ordered properly, not alphabetically
setDT(DATA)[, action := ordered(action, levels = c("signature", "ratification"))]

# order the rows to make sure that signature row and ratification row are
# subsequent for each agreement and country
setorder(DATA, Agreement_number, country, action)

# copy the ratification date from the row below but only within each group
result <- DATA[, ratification_date := shift(ratification_date, type = "lead"), 
                by = c("Agreement_number", "country")][
                  # keep only signature rows, remove action column
                  action == "signature"][, action := NULL]
result
```

> ```
>    Agreement_number country signature_date ratification_date dummy1 dummy2
> 1:                1  Canada           2000              2001      2      D
> 2:                1     USA           2000              2002      3      A
> 3:                2  Canada           2001              2001      1      B
> 4:                2     USA           2002              2002      4      C
> ```

#### Data

The OP has mentioned that his production data has 270 columns. To simulate this I've added two dummy columns:

```
set.seed(123L)
DATA <- data.frame(Agreement_number = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
country = c("Canada","Canada", "USA", "USA", "Canada","Canada", "USA", "USA"), 
action = c("signature", "ratification","signature", "ratification", "signature", "ratification","signature", "ratification"), 
signature_date = c(2000,NA,2000,NA, 2001, NA, 2002, NA),
ratification_date = c(NA, 2001, NA, 2002, NA, 2001, NA, 2002),
dummy1 = rep(sample(4), each = 2L),
dummy2 = rep(sample(LETTERS[1:4]), each = 2L))
```

Note that `set.seed()` is used for repeatable results when sampling.

> ```
>   Agreement_number country       action signature_date ratification_date dummy1 dummy2
> 1                1  Canada    signature           2000                NA      2      D
> 2                1  Canada ratification             NA              2001      2      D
> 3                1     USA    signature           2000                NA      3      A
> 4                1     USA ratification             NA              2002      3      A
> 5                2  Canada    signature           2001                NA      1      B
> 6                2  Canada ratification             NA              2001      1      B
> 7                2     USA    signature           2002                NA      4      C
> 8                2     USA ratification             NA              2002      4      C
> ```

#### Addendum: `dcast()` with additional columns

[Harland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427418/3817004) has suggested to use `data.table` and `dcast()`. Besides several other flaws in his answer, it doesn't handle the additional columns the OP has mentioned.

The `dcast()` approach below will return also the additional columns:

```
library(data.table)

# coerce to data table
setDT(DATA)[, action := ordered(action, levels = c("signature", "ratification"))]

# use already existing column to "coalesce" dates
DATA[action == "ratification", signature_date := ratification_date]
DATA[, ratification_date := NULL]

# dcast from long to wide form, note that ... refers to all other columns
result <- dcast(DATA, Agreement_number + country + ... ~ action, 
                value.var = "signature_date")
result
```

> ```
>    Agreement_number country dummy1 dummy2 signature ratification
> 1:                1  Canada      2      D      2000         2001
> 2:                1     USA      3      A      2000         2002
> 3:                2  Canada      1      B      2001         2001
> 4:                2     USA      4      C      2002         2002
> ```

Note that this approach will change the order of columns.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need `dcast`.  The version in the `data.table` library calls itself "fast", and in my experience, it is speedy on large datasets.

First, let's create one column which is either the `signature_date` or `ratification_date`, depending on the action

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA)[, date := ifelse(action == "ratification", ratification_date, signature_date)]
```

Now, let's cast it so that the action are the columns and the value is the date

```
wide <- dcast(DATA, Agreement_number + country ~ action, value.var = 'date')
```

So wide looks like this

```
  Agreement_number country ratification signature
1                1  Canada         2001      2000
2                1     USA         2002      2000
3                2  Canada         2001      2001
4                2     USA         2002      2002
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer contains several flaws: (1) `dcast()` is available from two packages: `reshape2` and `data.table`. The relevant call to `library()` is missing. (2) Even if `data.table` is loaded, it will dispatch the slower `reshape2` version if a data.frame is passed to `dcast()`. To use the faster version, `DATA` needs to be coerced to an object of class `data.table`. This code is also missing. (3) The calculation of the additional column `DATA$date` is *not* using the efficient `data.table` syntax. (4) It doesn't handle any additional columns.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism.  What is the best course of remedy for this?  Should I try to edit the answer to address these flaws, or simply delete it as there are now better answers here?

Comment: Please, do *not' delete your answer. You were first with the `dcast()` approach and my answer is refering to it. Please, improve yoru answer as far as you can.

Comment: For learning `data.table` I recommend the vignettes and the FAQ on  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started, and chapter 3 of Frank's *Quick R Tutorial* http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/

Answer (score 2):

Here is another `data.table` solution using uwe-block's data.frame. It is similar to uwe-block's method, but uses `max` to collapse the data.

```
# covert data.frame to data.table and factor variables to character variables
library(data.table)
setDT(DATA)[, names(DATA) := lapply(.SD,
                                    function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x)]

# collapse data set, by agreement and country. Take max of remaining variables.
 DATA[, lapply(.SD, max, na.rm=TRUE), by=.(Agreement_number, country)][,action := NULL][]
```

The `lapply` runs through variables not included in the by statement and calculates the maximum after removing NA values. The next link in the chain drops the unneeded action variable and the final (unnecessary) link prints the output.

This returns

```
   Agreement_number country signature_date ratification_date dummy1 dummy2
1:                1  Canada           2000              2001      2      D
2:                1     USA           2000              2002      3      A
3:                2  Canada           2001              2001      1      B
4:                2     USA           2002              2002      4      C
```